# post json data after getJson in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, get

I have a question about how to use both GET and POST at the same time.
What I'm trying to do is that before saving the form, I want to verify that the new user name does not already exist.

```
{ “status”: “success”, “results” : [ { “id” : 1, “name” : “John Smith”, “password”: “123456” }, { “id”: 2, “name” : “Jane Doe”, “password”: “654321” } ] }
```

I want to write code to validate that user name doesn't already exist before saving the form. If the user name exists, I want to show an alert to the browser. If there are no errors, I want to submit the form.

Here's what I got so far! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
var username = $('#user_name').val();

$.getJSON('user.json', function(data) {

    var results = data.results;
    var match = false;

    $.each(results, function(i, result) {
        if(result.name === username) {
            match = true;
        }
    });

    if(!match) {
        console.log("POST");
        // Submit the form!


    } else {
        alert("Username already exists!");
    }

});

});
```

Is there better way to do this? even without using jQuery? what would be good reasons to use jQuery?

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the below code to send some data in json format.

```
if(!match) {
        console.log("POST");

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url : ?,
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        context : Form,
        success : function(callback){
            //Where $(this) => context == FORM
            console.log(JSON.parse(callback));
            $(this).html("Success!");
        },
        error : function(){
            $(this).html("Error!");
        }
    });
}
```

remove data : JSON.stringify(data),  incase you dont need.

Comment: what does cache and context do?

Comment: let me know if your problem is resolved. 

you can use POST method a you want to post some data to any function. 
and cache: false,, i guess you wont require it.